# Processing of data in multiple selection screens in ABAP

Tags: abap

I am trying to do a program in ABAP using multiple selection screens. In the first selection screen there are two push buttons. If I click on first push button, another selection screen appears and I need to enter a parameter in the input field and fetch data from database based on that parameter. Similarly, on clicking another push button, another selection screen appears where I again need to enter a parameter in the input field and fetch data from database. The logic of the second and third selection screens are different. I mean to say, search queries are different. I am not able to find out how to handle these things with multiple selection screens. What shall I write in at selection screen output? I am a newbie when it comes to ABAP.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has lead you to the conclusion that selection screens are the way to go?

Comment: My question is that I want to have a drop down list in two selection screens. Now, how I will write the code in at selection screen output. There will be two logic in at selection screen output for two different selection screens. Please explain me the process.

Comment: You could try tabstrips on the selection screen.

Comment: you could put everything on one selection screen, first make most parts invisible, later make visible what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with multiple selection screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840584/problems-with-multiple-selection-screens)

Comment: You could check sy-dynnr to evaluate which screen you're currently at. You would process the function codes in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` event, not `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`.