# Problems with multiple selection screens

Tags: list, events, abap, dynpro

`START-OF-SELECTION` is not getting triggered in my program. I am trying to fetch book details based on book name and book author using multiple selection screens in ABAP. There are two pushbuttons and based on those selection screens are opened. When I click any of the push buttons, then selection screens are opened. But after I select entries from the dropdown list and click execute button, then the transaction goes to the initial screen with the pushbuttons. The book details are not displayed at all. `START-OF-SELECTION` is not triggered. Please help, I am a newbie in ABAP. Here is my program

```
 REPORT y_multiple_screen.

    TABLES: sscrfields.
    TYPE-POOLS: vrm.
    DATA: param    TYPE vrm_id,
          values   TYPE vrm_values,
          wa_value LIKE LINE OF values.



    DATA: it_ybook TYPE TABLE OF ybook,
          wa_ybook TYPE ybook.


    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_book> TYPE ybook.


    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK blocker WITH FRAME TITLE text-001 NO INTERVALS.
    SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON (30)  w_butn1 USER-COMMAND but1.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON (30)  w_butn2 USER-COMMAND but2.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
    SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP.

    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK blocker.

    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1100.
    PARAMETERS: p_author TYPE char255 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20.


    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1100.

    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1200.

    PARAMETERS: p_bname TYPE char255 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20.


    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1200.

    INITIALIZATION.

      w_butn1 = 'Search by author name'.
      w_butn2 = 'Search by book name'.

      "At selection-screen output.

    AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
      IF sscrfields-ucomm EQ 'BUT1'.

        CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1100.


      ELSEIF sscrfields-ucomm EQ 'BUT2'.

        CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1200.
      ENDIF.

    AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.

      CLEAR it_ybook.
      SELECT *
      FROM ybook
      INTO TABLE it_ybook.
      CLEAR values.
      CLEAR wa_ybook.
      CLEAR wa_value.
      LOOP AT it_ybook INTO wa_ybook.


        wa_value-key = wa_ybook-book_author.
        wa_value-text = wa_ybook-book_author.

        APPEND  wa_value TO values.
        CLEAR wa_ybook.
        CLEAR wa_value.
      ENDLOOP.



      CLEAR it_ybook.



      CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
        EXPORTING
          id              = 'P_AUTHOR'
          values          = values
        EXCEPTIONS
          id_illegal_name = 1
          OTHERS          = 2.


      CLEAR it_ybook.
      SELECT *
      FROM ybook
      INTO TABLE it_ybook.

      "CLEAR values.
      CLEAR wa_ybook.
      CLEAR wa_value.

      LOOP AT it_ybook INTO wa_ybook.


        wa_value-key = wa_ybook-book_name.
        wa_value-text = wa_ybook-book_name.

        APPEND  wa_value TO values.
        CLEAR wa_ybook.
        CLEAR wa_value.
      ENDLOOP.



      CLEAR it_ybook.



      CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
        EXPORTING
          id              = 'P_BNAME'
          values          = values
        EXCEPTIONS
          id_illegal_name = 1
          OTHERS          = 2.


    START-OF-SELECTION.
        WRITE:/10 'Book ID',40 'Book Name',70 'Book Author',100 'Book Price'.

        CLEAR it_ybook.
        CLEAR wa_ybook.
        SELECT *
        FROM ybook
        INTO TABLE it_ybook
        WHERE book_name = p_bname.
        LOOP AT it_ybook INTO wa_ybook.
          WRITE:/10 wa_ybook-book_id,40 wa_ybook-book_name,70 wa_ybook-book_author,100 wa_ybook-book_price.
          CLEAR wa_ybook.
        ENDLOOP.


        WRITE:/10 'Book ID',40 'Book Name',70 'Book Author',100 'Book Price'.

        CLEAR it_ybook.
        CLEAR wa_ybook.
        SELECT *
        FROM ybook
        INTO TABLE it_ybook
        WHERE book_author = p_author.
        LOOP AT it_ybook INTO wa_ybook.
          WRITE:/10 wa_ybook-book_id,40 wa_ybook-book_name,70 wa_ybook-book_author,100 wa_ybook-book_price.
          CLEAR wa_ybook.
        ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I want to do this program using selection screens only. I think this scenario can be solved using other techniques. But please help me in doing this program using selection screens.

Comment: What happens when you push start on after returning to the first selection screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`START-OF-SELECTION` will only trigger off your main screen (when you hit execute on the first screen).

You can force the event by changing the `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` block:

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  IF sscrfields-ucomm EQ 'BUT1'.

    CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1100.
    if sy-subrc = 0.  "the user clicked the execute button
      sscrfields-ucomm = 'ONLI'.  "set the system command for the next screen to execute
    endif.

  ELSEIF sscrfields-ucomm EQ 'BUT2'.

    CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1200.
    if sy-subrc = 0.  "the user clicked the execute button
      sscrfields-ucomm = 'ONLI'.  "set the system command for the next screen to execute
    endif.

  ENDIF.
```

Comment: Can you give me a brief idea about selection-screen events?very much confused what to write on which events

Comment: ONLI in this case is the user command that is linked to the execute button. By forcing the value sscrfields-ucomm = 'ONLI', at the next PBO of the selection screen it will automatically excecute and not stop on the first selection screen as it did before.

Try this link for an explanation of events (it is also well documented in SAP Help) http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Selection+Screen+Events+in+ABAP

I have never used selection screens in this way; I can't really think of a real-world situation where this would be a good solution.  I'm assuming that you're just experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `START-OF-SELECTION` block at all.
 
Firstly, add user commands to your parameters:

```
PARAMETERS: p_author TYPE char255 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20 USER-COMMAND auth.
PARAMETERS: p_bname TYPE char255 AS LISTBOX VISIBLE LENGTH 20 USER-COMMAND name.
```

Afterwards move your dropdown coding to `INITIALIZATION` block:

```
INITIALIZATION.

  w_butn1 = 'Search by author name'.
  w_butn2 = 'Search by book name'.

  CLEAR it_ybook.
  SELECT *
  FROM ybook
  ...
  ...
  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    EXPORTING
      id              = 'P_BNAME'
      values          = values
    EXCEPTIONS
      id_illegal_name = 1
      OTHERS          = 2.
```

Then correct `AT-SELECTION-SCREEN` event like this:

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
CASE sscrfields-ucomm.
    WHEN 'BUT1'.
      CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1100.
    WHEN 'BUT2'.
      CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 1200.
    WHEN 'AUTH'.
      LEAVE TO LIST-PROCESSING.
      SET PF-STATUS space.
      SUPPRESS DIALOG.
    WHEN 'NAME'.
      LEAVE TO LIST-PROCESSING.
      SET PF-STATUS space.
      SUPPRESS DIALOG.
    WHEN OTHERS.
  ENDCASE.
```

And place your output coding here as well. Your lists will be output right on selecting value in dropdown list.

Remember that selection screen parameters are converted to uppercase by default, consequently your output selects will return no rows in the above given form. So for proper use you should convert them to lowercase like this:

```
TRANSLATE p_author TO LOWER CASE.
```

**UPDATE:** 
 `LEAVE-TO-LIST-PROCESSING` [statement](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapleave_to_list-processing.htm) interrupts the current Dynpro sequence processing (but finishes the current Dynpro!) and switches to lists that were buffered on AS until that moment. You should learn more about [list processing](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/EN/e4/2adbe9449911d1949c0000e8353423/content.htm) here. This technique is treated obsolete, but, as you chose it, you should definitely know it:) `SET PF-STATUS space` sets default dialog status for lists. You can learn about dialog statuses from the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/dba34635c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).
What concerns your code, you can merge 2 loop statements into one. Another suggestion is to eliminate DB selects during output at all: you don't do any data modifications here so data won't change after `INITIALIZATION` block. And finally, you can intensify using of field-symbols as they consume less resourcess comparing to work areas. So your code should look like:
INITIALIZATION.

```
TYPE-POOLS: vrm.
DATA: it_ybook TYPE TABLE OF ybook.
DATA: param    TYPE vrm_id,
      values_auth   TYPE vrm_values,
      values_name   TYPE vrm_values,
      wa_value_auth TYPE LINE OF vrm_values,
      wa_value_name TYPE LINE OF vrm_values.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_ybook> TYPE ybook.

  w_butn1 = 'Search by author name'.
  w_butn2 = 'Search by book name'.

  CLEAR: it_ybook, wa_value_auth, wa_value_name.

  SELECT *
    FROM ybook
    INTO TABLE it_ybook.

  LOOP AT it_ybook ASSIGNING <fs_ybook>.

    wa_value_auth-key = <fs_ybook>-book_author.
    wa_value_auth-text = <fs_ybook>-book_author.

    wa_value_name-key = <fs_ybook>-book_name.
    wa_value_name-text = <fs_ybook>-book_name.

    APPEND wa_value_auth TO values_auth.
    APPEND wa_value_name TO values_name.

  ENDLOOP.

  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES' "for authors

  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES' "for names
```

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.

```
    CASE sscrfields-ucomm.
     ...
    ENDCASE.

    TRANSLATE P_BNAME TO LOWER CASE.
    LOOP AT it_ybook ASSIGNING <fs_ybook> WHERE book_name = P_BNAME.
      WRITE:/10 'Book ID',40 'Book Name',70 'Book Author',100 'Book Price'.
      WRITE:/10 <fs_ybook>-book_id,40 <fs_ybook>-book_name,70 <fs_ybook>-book_author,100 <fs_ybook>-book_price.
    ENDLOOP.

    TRANSLATE P_AUTHOR TO LOWER CASE.
    LOOP AT it_ybook ASSIGNING <fs_ybook> WHERE book_author = P_AUTHOR.
      WRITE:/10 'Book ID',40 'Book Name',70 'Book Author',100 'Book Price'.
      WRITE:/10 <fs_ybook>-book_id,40 <fs_ybook>-book_name,70 <fs_ybook>-book_author,100 <fs_ybook>-book_price.
    ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Why at selection-screen output is not needed?.Can I write the same code in initialization that I have written in at selection-screen output?

Comment: Can you give me the order on which initialization, at selection-screen, at selection-screen output are called?

Comment: Actually I am a newbie in ABAP.I am little confused about these events.What things should I write in those events?

Comment: Of course, you can write in the `INITIALIZATION` any code you want, including those you placed in `AT-SELECTION-SCREEN-OUTPUT`. You should bear in mind, that `INITIALIZATION` is called *only once*, so you should place there code that should be executed once, and populating dropdowns exactly matches this definition. You should learn more about Dynpro events [here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Selection+Screen+Events+in+ABAP) or [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/56/1eb6c705ad11d2952f0000e8353423/frameset.htm)

Comment: OK.Thanks Suncatcher.

Comment: One more thing. In at selection-screen event, what does the code means that you have written under when 'Auth'? What is leave to list processing and pf status?.Could you please explain them?

Comment: Since I am using two drop downs in my program, so I am calling vrm_set_values twice with different parameters. I have written the code. But still have confusions.Is my process of writing that portion of the code correct?.Please give some suggestions.

Comment: @user3621835, added answers to your questions and code to update